# Karate - using waitUntil with xPath (span text comparison)

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate I need to wait for text in specific SPAN to be loaded (first state is "LOADING" and I need to wait for "READY". I used "waitUntil" function with xPath, but it does not works:

```
* waitUntil("//td[normalize-space(text()) = \'' + servName + '\']/../td[6]/span == 'READY'")
```

While having set in background:

```
* configure connectTimeout = 120000
* configure readTimeout = 120000
* configure retry = {count:40, interval:3000}
```

The status from LOADING to READY is changed aprox. after 60seconds. But when I use this waitUntil function, all timeout passes (40x 3000ms) and in cucumber report I can see:

```
23:29:37.464 waitUntil (js) - retry #40
23:29:40.473 failed after 40 retries and 120544 milliseconds
```

But the row in report with this step failure is green (I have no idea why) and the test continues to next steps.

Could you please help me with some advice what is wrong with the waitUntil function I have used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open bug for waits that most likely includes `waitUntil()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1125

It would really help us if you follow this process and confirm that it is indeed fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide - do consider taking the help of someone who knows Java if needed, but the process is actually quite simple.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have used "waitForText()" instead of "waitUntil" and it worked for me.